# Submit Apple Watch app to App Store

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm going to make an app for the Apple Watch, but I don't know how much time I have to release it. When's the start date to submit Apple Watch enabled apps to the App Store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has opened submitting WatchKit apps now.

[image]

Comment: Is it compulsory to have iPhone app and Apple Watch app . I want to develop Apple Watch app but i dont want to develop iPhone app. I will just create 1 page iPhone app showing information about Apple Watch.. Will it be accepted or I have to create complete iPhone app with Apple watch as well.

Comment: You need to have an iPhone app and it can't be a trivial app.  Your Watch App doesn't actually run code on the watch, it is just an extension of your iPhone app and it runs on the iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official date yet.  The bottom of https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/ says.

> Please Note: Apps built with Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 SDK may be
>   submitted to the App Store. However, WatchKit extensions are not
>   accepted at this time.

Also the iTunes Connect documentation says that you must submit Watch App screen shots taken on an actual Apple Watch.  Unless you can go to an Apple Watch Lab to take those screen shots I am not sure you will be able to submit before the Watch launches on April 24.

Comment: The screenshot requirement has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I just got an email from Apple stating "Submit your WatchKit apps now". It also says:

> Once your WatchKit app is approved and released by Apple, your existing iPhone users will receive the app update and customers will see your WatchKit extension icon and description on the App Store. A small group of people who currently have an Apple Watch will be able to use your WatchKit app before April 24, so make sure your back end systems are ready.